# AddPrinterDriver failed but completed successfully

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

I have downloaded Konica Minolta Magicolor 2530 DL printer drivers for Windows 7 x64 from the [Konica Europe Website](http://www.konicaminolta.eu/en/business-solutions/support/download-center.html) (mainly because it's not available on the [US website](http://printer.konicaminolta.com/support/current_printers/mc2530dl_sup.htm#64)).

During installation via Setup.exe it says

```
AddPrinterDriver failed!
pName:       KONICA MINOLTA magicolor 2530DL
pDriverFile: C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\x64\MIMFN506.DLL
pDataFile:   MSDMLT06.SDD
pConfigFile: C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\x64\MNT5UI06.DLL 
The operation completed successfully.
```

The printer is turned on. I can access the web page of the printer through the browser.

What could I try to make the printer work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't install the printer via Setup.exe, use the Windows `Add printer` functionality.

- Choose `local printer`, even the printer is connected to the network. Network printers are meant to be printers which are connected to someone else's PC.
- Create a `Standard TCP/IP port` and enter the IP address
- Choose `Have disk`
- Select `mXP___06.inf` (or any other INF file if there's only one) in the folder of the Setup